# Unable to install certificates for Emulator v4.4 in android

Tags: certificate, sd-card

Iam unable to install certificates to android emulator 4.4.
Under Options Security > Install From Sd card in emulator,it directs me to Downloads page where no certificates are shown and i have already pushed certificate to sd card of emulator.
Working fine for v4.3

Please help me out....

Answer (score 0):

I've used this tool.

http://www.realmb.com/droidCert/

You upload the certificate to their site and then they give you a url that you can download the certificate from on the android device and it launches the installer automatically for you.